# Explicit diffeomorphism between an infinite dimensional sphere its product with itself

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Let $S$ be an infinite dimensional sphere in a Hillbert space.

As $S$ is homotopic to the product $S \times S$, then $S$ is diffeomorphic to $S \times S$ (for Hilbert manifolds, a homotopy equivalence implies diffeomorphism).

Is there an explicit diffeomorphism between $S$ and $S \times S$?

Comment: I don't have access to this paper at the moment, but this may follow from ["Every infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is diffeomorphic with its unit sphere"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=193646), since certainly the underlying Hilbert space is diffeomorphic to the direct sum with itself.